# adding UITableView with code

Tags: iphone

I am very very new to the iPhone programming. I am kind of playing with the sample code.
My first question is if it is possible to add the `UITableView` with the code only.
If it is then here is my code that i am trying to add `UITableView` to the navigation controller.

```
analyticsTable = [[UITableView alloc] init];    
[self.view.window addSubview:analyticsTable];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

I dont know how to go about it

Thanks
Varun

Comment: You shouldn't add the table as a subview of the window, add it as a subview of the viewcontroller's view (self.view).  Also, don't remove the view from the superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the docs provided by Apple at
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Check about halfway down the bottom in the section "Creating a Table View Programmatically". I think that's exactly what you want.

These taught me how to programmatically do tables. I've never needed to use IB.

Comment: [Direct Link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW4) to sample.  Make a view controller for the table view, then push the view controller onto your navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks John, I tried the solution on Apple's website and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I am sorry i am still new to the forum. Didnt know that once you get the solution right you need to checkmark.

Done
Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a frame, delegate and datasource.  See this for more info

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/52938-uitableview-programmatically-creating-adding-datasource-delegate.html

Read to the bottom.